# RaphaelJS: Viewbox problems with IE8 and lower

Tags: internet-explorer-8, svg, maps, raphael

Hello I've got a strange bug and no idea why it happens!

To show you the bug I have prepared something for you: [jsfiddle example](http://goo.gl/mwAzm)

Watch the page in IE9 and then switch to IE8 mode, and you will see that the map of germany will not be fit to the container. This problem just appears in Internet Explorer 8 or lower. In IE9 or other browsers, like Chrome, Safari, Firefox or Opera it is working fine, as expected.

Maybe you have any ideas, what I can do better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the raphael irc chat, which helped me fix this:

```
var svg = new Raphael(document.getElementById('map'), '260px', '185px');
```

The constructor instead expects integer values for width and height:

```
var svg = new Raphael(document.getElementById('map'), 260, 185);
```